# Is it possible to add a case to an existing enumeration where there is no source?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I am implementing my own TableView because I would like to have special animation when reloading a row using `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation`.

The problem is that I need to give a type of animation when I'm calling this method. So I would like to know if it's possible to add an extra case to `UITableViewRowAnimation` enumeration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible, for at least one reason: switch statements not using a `default` case wouldn't compile, because they would be missing the newly added case.

Consider this enum:

```
enum TestEnum {
    case ONE
    case TWO
}
```

and some code using it:

```
let testOne = TestEnum.ONE

switch testOne {
case .ONE:
    println("one")

case .TWO:
    println("two")
}
```

If you were able to add one or more cases in an extension:

```
extension TestEnum {
    case THREE
}
```

then the switch statement written above wouldn't compile because the new case is not handled.